# How to return the index of a column containing minimum value in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, minimum

Suppsoe I have a 100X10 dataframe. For each row, I want to add an extra column which contains the column number containing the minimum value. Also this function to be applied only for specific columns say column No. 6 to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using @akrun's `df1`

```
df1$index_col <- apply(df1[,6:10],1,which.min)+5
```

Comment: my dataset was small (100K rows) , so apply also worked pretty fast. anyways thanks guys !!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `max.col`

```
transform(df1, newCol = (max.col(-1*df1[6:10], "first"))+5)
```

NOTE: The `max.col` approach would be very fast compared to any loop or `apply` based approach.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*10), ncol=10))
```